# sudo apt-get update: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install a new virtual environment to for django using python 2.7.

I have run the command sudo apt-get update and I get the following error

Reading package lists... Error!
W: GPG error: http://za.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key 
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/za.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
michael@Bumblebee:~$

I then try and  run sudo apt-get install python-pip

Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/za.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
michael@Bumblebee:~$

I have no clue whats happening here can someone help

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your Ubuntu package provider mirror `za.archive.ubuntu.com` is not working correctly. This question is not related to Django or Python, but is specific to how to install Ubuntu packages.

Try changing your Ubuntu package mirror to one of alternative Ubuntu mirrors.

[Here is a short answer on Ubuntu Stack Exchange how to do it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main).